# Autostart download of file on website?

Tags: html, file, user-interface, download

How do i automaticly start a file for download when a user clicks a link?
For example when a user clicks a link that allows them to download a image.

Like it works on www.iStockphoto.com

Comment: Perhaps my question should say, How do i autostart download of a imagefile when user opens a page. I think that is what happens on Istock. SO to say, user clicks a link that leads to a html page and then imagefile download start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="path-to-file.jpeg">link</a>
```

Along with a [content-disposition](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) header that makes it an attachment.

Comment: COuld you give me an example of the content-disposition header? Can i change this header with PHP?

Comment: @jamietelin — There is an entire section of the spec I linked to marked "Examples", and yes, you can change it with PHP (although you would then have to manually pass the rest of the data for the file)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I was looking for. Hopefully it will help other people looking for an answer.

Create a file called *downloadfile.php* for example and add the following;

```
$file = $_GET['file'];
if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
```

Then you can add a link to that file like this:

```
<a href="downloadfile.php?file=dog.jpg">Download image!</a>
```

Of course this is just an example. It can be done in various ways. Important syntaxes to remember are header() and readfile()

Comment: That was already answered. Just set content-disposition header to attachment. That's all. The remnant is optional.

Comment: I know, its my own question. Just wanted to make the answer more clear. Not everyone enjoy reading 11 pages of text :) (Also in David Dorward answer i find this a bit confusing; <a href="path-to-file.jpeg">link</a>